# tightness probability measure in polish space and its equivalence

Tags: probability-theory

Let $P_n$ is probability measure in $(S, \mathcal{S})$ ($S$ is polish space). Then $P_n$ is tight iff there exist random variable $X : S \to [0, \infty]$ such that

(1)$\{X\leq c\}$ is compact for all $0<c<\infty$

(2)$P_n (X= \infty) = 0 $

(3) $\sup_n E_n X < \infty $

I solved <= by setting $K_n = \{X\leq n\}$, then since $\sup_n E_n X < \infty $, $P_m (X \in K_n) \to 1$ uniformly for $m$. However, how can I approach to => side?

Currently, I learned about several convergence mode and Prohorov theorem, which means relatively compactness is equivalent to tightness when $S$ is polish.

This problem is last year qualification exam in my school. Thank you.